# Active state for radio button labels with no value

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CMS that outputs radio buttons without a value field. I think I could've target each field based on its value with jQuery to assign "active" class but I don't have that option now. Is there a way to assign and style the 'active' item with either CSS or jQuery for this? Please note, the current CSS is hiding the input radio buttons and it's showing the labels only. So the active state should be assigned and styles for labels.

```
<div class="form_responses">
<div class="form_response">
    <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_1" type="radio" data-text="Yes" name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e" checked="checked" value="923518fd-e6ce-4989-8342-15d9b22e5a20" autocomplete="off" required="required" data-handler-change="1">
    <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_1">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form_response">
    <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_2" type="radio" data-text="Undecided" name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e" value="cff8e508-ba35-4e2b-99d6-fa375f1fc2da" autocomplete="off" required="required" data-handler-change="1">
    <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_2">Undecided</label>
</div>
```

[**Here's a Live demo of the radio buttons**](https://codepen.io/WpEmbraded/pen/MWjBodp)

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}
.form_response > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    background-color: #182B54;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.form_response > label:hover {
    color: #182B54;
    background-color: #FED007;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_responses">
    <div class="form_response">
        <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_1" type="radio" data-text="Yes" name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e" checked="checked" value="923518fd-e6ce-4989-8342-15d9b22e5a20" autocomplete="off" required="required" data-handler-change="1">
        <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_1">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_response">
        <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_2" type="radio" data-text="Undecided" name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e" value="cff8e508-ba35-4e2b-99d6-fa375f1fc2da" autocomplete="off" required="required" data-handler-change="1">
        <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_2">Undecided</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: these radio have their value attribute. They appear to be fully valid imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to style the label that immediately follows (as a sibling) any radio that has the attribute `checked="checked"`. **This is all you should need to add:**

```
input[type='radio'][checked='checked']+label {
  background: red;
}
```

The above CSS finds all inputs of type radio, with the attribute checked="checked", and applies a style if the next tag to follow this item is a `label`. In your example this is all you need to make the styling work.

If you also need a `jquery` function to help toggle the radio buttons then I have added this. I have had to guess how your code identifies different elements because you have provided all the HTML. This might need adaptation depending on the rest of your HTML. This will use the `checked='checked'` attributes of the radio options, but you can also uncomment some code to add an `.active` class if you prefer (this is unnecessary if you use the `css` styling given above.

All `jquery` lines are commented.

---

```js
// Add click event to labels
$("label").click(function() {

  // Store the name of the radio 
  radioName = $(this).attr("for")

  // Remove radio specific identifier (i.e. _1) to get form name 
  formName = radioName.substring(0, radioName.length - 2);

  // Remove all checked attributes from radio buttons who are wrapped in the .radio-group
  $("input[type='radio'][name='" + formName + "']").removeAttr("checked");

  // Uncomment the line below if you want to use an active class name
  // $("input[type='radio'][name='" + formName +"']").removeClass("active");

  // Find 'for' attribute
  labelFor = $(this).attr("for");

  // Add checked attribute to the clicked radio
  $("input#" + labelFor).attr("checked", "checked");

  // Uncomment the line below if you want to use an active class name
  // $("input#" + labelFor).addClass("active");


});
```

```css
input[type='radio'][checked='checked']+label {
  background: red;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.form_response>label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #182B54;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.form_response>label:hover {
  color: #182B54;
  background-color: #FED007;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="<form id=" form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e ">
<div class="form_response ">
    <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_1 " type="radio " data-text="Yes " name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e " checked="checked " value="923518fd-e6ce-4989-8342-15d9b22e5a20 " autocomplete="off " required="required
  " data-handler-change="1 ">
    <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_1 ">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_response ">
    <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_2 " type="radio " data-text="Undecided " name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e " value="cff8e508-ba35-4e2b-99d6-fa375f1fc2da " autocomplete="off " required="required
  " data-handler-change="1 ">
    <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8e_2 ">Undecided</label>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f ">
  <div class="form_response ">
    <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f_3 " type="radio " data-text="Yes " name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f " checked="checked " value="923518fd-e6ce-4989-8342-15d9b22e5a20 " autocomplete="off " required="required
  " data-handler-change="1 ">
    <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f_3 ">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_response ">
    <input id="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f_4 " type="radio " data-text="Undecided " name="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f " value="cff8e508-ba35-4e2b-99d6-fa375f1fc2da " autocomplete="off " required="required
  " data-handler-change="1 ">
    <label for="form_3c0cb7b9-a09a-4a95-be27-e27923448c8f_4 ">Undecided</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oliver, thank you for the specific explanation. The CMS does not allow any modifications to the markup, it outputs the radio buttons exactly as shown in my code. Can I apply the checked="checked" with jQuery upon a click on the label? And then apply your code on top of that? I did try that but can't see to find a way to target the click on the label.

Comment: I've updated my answer to change the `checked` attribute depending on `label` `clicks`. You should be able to adapt this to your needs